# excel - compare ID and Date then generate sequence number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My column A contains ID and column B contain Dates. What I want to do is I need to check Column A and B to check whether it's duplicated, if yes, then i need to generate sequence number in column C.

```
Example:
1001  01/01/2018  1
1001  01/01/2018  2
1001  01/01/2018  3
1001  03/01/2018  1
1001  03/01/2018  2 
1002  01/01/2018  1
1002  01/01/2018  2
```

I know, I need to use IF condition but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entries are always sorted nicely like this example you could use the following if statement placed in cell C2 and fill it down.

```
=IF(AND(A1=A2,B1=B2),C1+1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also discovered to use this condition from another forum just now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to add "helper" column and use `COUNTIF`.

Using your example data:

[image: img]

**Formula in C2:**

```
=A2&B2
```

**Formula in D2:**

```
=COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)
```